# gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input

Tags: linux, architecture, public-key-encryption, gnupg, snakeyaml

When decrypting I get following error:

```
$ eyaml decrypt -s 'ENC and the key goes on here'
```

```
.gnupg --quiet --no-secmem-warning --no-permission-warning --no-tty --yes --decrypt)
failed with: gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input
```

I have checked my keys, everything is in order. At this point I am out of options.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a simpler command and update the question? I got the same error with a simple `gpg --edit-key <my key id>` which was resolved by Josh Habdas' answer.

Answer (score 64):

If you configured [Automatic Git commit signing with GPG on macOS](https://gist.github.com/bmhatfield/cc21ec0a3a2df963bffa3c1f884b676b) and you see this error comment out `no-tty` in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659198/gpg-sorry-no-terminal-at-all-requested-cant-get-input/51174117#comment88837127_40393581) by [Fahl-Design](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3578430/fahl-design).

[image]

This will also allow you to generate new GPG keys following the [GitHub instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/) for new keys.

Answer (score 19):

You need to remove the option `--no-tty`

> --no-tty
>   Make sure that the TTY (terminal) is never used for any output. This option is needed in some cases because GnuPG sometimes
>   prints warnings to the TTY even if --batch is used.

Comment: if someone else finds this question/answer with other gpg commands check your `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` for the **no-tty** seting and disable it

Comment: @josh-habdas yes, your are right. But I found this question by the error message title and had "no-tty" in my config (to use singed git commits with phpstorm)

Comment: Can I disable that option temporarily or per command?

Answer (score 8):

For those who are encountering this error from scripts that are running with no TTY available, adding `--batch` to the GPG command line, or `batch` to a line in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` can make the problem go away.

Comment: This helps for me to open

Comment: This helped me, but a more permanent and global solution would be to follow @JamalMcCrackin suggestion in a note to oden's answer: to edit your ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf by deleting your no-tty seting in case you have it there.

Comment: Depends on the situation. Some people are running GPG from a terminal and disabling `no-tty` would fix their problem. In my case, I was running GPG without a controlling tty, so I had to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my git email so that it matched the email on my gpg key and the primary email on my Github.

```
$ git config --global user.email "myemailaddress@gmail.com"
```