# GitHub Actions - gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input

Tags: java, maven, github-actions, gnupg, maven-gpg-plugin

**Objective** - I am currently trying to automate the deployment of a Java package to Maven Central through GitHub Actions. As publishing requires to sign artifacts I added **maven-gpg-plugin** to `pom.xml`. So far, so good.

**Situation** - When the plugin got loaded, it fails on execution and then prompting this:

```
gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input
```

A solution suggested by [this another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40393581/10013088) on the same topic is to remove the `--no-tty` option set by default in the **gpg.conf** file.

**Problem** - Here is the thing. It doesn't appear we can alter this file using the actions/setup-java@v3 from GitHub Actions which yet exposes the possibility to provide GPG private key and passphrase.

[Here](https://github.com/Lycoon/clash-api/blob/dev/.github/workflows/deploy.yml) is the GitHub actions deployment workflow file and [here](https://github.com/Lycoon/clash-api/blob/dev/pom.xml) the associated pom.xml. Am I missing something?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/sualeh/ae78dc16123899d7942bc38baba5203c.

Comment: Thanks! I've stumbled on upon that way of doing earlier but I'd rather prefer to use the provided built-in parameter of setup-java action for the sake of consistency. That will be my last option for sure if there is no other way around

Comment: No problem. Yes, that seems to be right way to automate this. You have already an active issue (https://github.com/actions/setup-java/issues/554) on the repo. Hopefully, you'll get the way forward with `actions/setup-java`.

Comment: Yes! I will make sure to update here as soon as I have hints about what's wrong ;)